Does anywhere restrict Salbutamol (inhaler for asthma)?
Up to now, I have not been concerned but other questions on medications have prompted me to check.
I have mild asthma, I rarely have an attack but I like to carry a Salbutamol inhaler as a precaution.  Normally, one in hand carry and one in check-in as a precaution.  It is prescribed.
I'm not sure whether it counts as a liquid but, when it is required to separate liquids, I include my inhaler.  So far, within Europe, US, and Canada, I have had no comments.  Neither that it is a problem nor that it should not be in the liquids bag.
Further afield, e.g. the Far East, do any countries restrict Salbutamol?

Medications are exempt from liquid restrictions.

@lambshaanxy Yes, but do you need to show them?

I can't give a legal answer, but i can give a practical one.
Over the past ~20 years I've travelled to around 50 countries across every continent except Antarctica, many of those countries multiple times. This includes over half the countries in Asia, and thus much of the Far East.
During all of those trips I've always had a Salbutamol inhaler in my carry-on baggage, and at no time have I ever had anyone at security or elsewhere show any interest in it.
I do NOT remove it from my bags (even when there is a need to remove liquids/etc), and have never been asked to remove it even after going the X-ray machine.

Thanks.  That matches my experience.  I had not thought to question it until I saw other questions on medicines and drugs.

Also, about 50 countries with many in Asia.  Right now, I am in Laos.

Same here: 40+ countries (including China, Vietnam, Thailand, Myanmar, Malaysia, Indonesia, etc) and never a problem. I DO take the inhaler out and put it with my toothpaste in clear baggie.
